# Add different custom tables to DOM by click event with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have the following table with buttons on a simple HTML.

I need the buttons to be able to remove the current table and draw a new table (with a different content) to the DOM without reloading the page. 
I have a JQuery method for removing the current table element, however I struggle with adding another table.

How can a table be added efficiently?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
.header-class{
 font-size:25px;
 font-family:cursive;
 background-color:lightgray;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.members {
 font-family:helvetica;
}
.blips {
 color:red;
}
.crudz {
 color:blue;
}
.satin-flings {
 color:rgb(213, 194, 0);
}
td {
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-left:10px;
 border: 10px;
}
</style>

<body>

<button class="tableRevmoveButton"> Remove table </button>
<button class="tableAddButton"> Add table </button>
<button class="tableAddNewButton"> Add different table </button>

<div class="tabel">
 <table class="itdev_people">
   <tr class="header-class">
      <td colspan="4">The Blips</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members blips">
      <td>Rotton </td>
      <td>Rob</td>
      <td>ttt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members blips">
      <td>Effram</td>
      <td>The Dumb Rabbot</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members blips">
      <td>Effram</td>
      <td>The Dumb Rabbot</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="header-class">
      <td colspan="2">The Crudz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members crudz">
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>"Sky" Halker</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members crudz">
      <td>Sparky</td>
      <td>That stupid Eagle</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="header-class">
      <td colspan="2">The Satin Flings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members satin-flings">
      <td>Josh-man</td>
      <td>McDanielson-man III</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members satin-flings">
      <td>Dominque</td>
      <td>The Christmas Donkey</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="header-class">
      <td colspan="2">The Satin Flings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members satin-flings">
      <td>Josh-man</td>
      <td>McDanielson-man III</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="members satin-flings">
      <td>Dominque</td>
      <td>The Christmas Donkey</td>
  </tr>

</table>
</div>

<script>
//Table action
$('.header-class').click(function() {
 console.log('clicked');
 if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
 $(this)
  .nextUntil('tr.header-class')
  .find('td')
  .parent()
  .find('td > div')
  .slideDown('fast', function() {
    var $set = $(this);
    $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
  });
 $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
} else {
$(this)
  .nextUntil('tr.header-class')
  .find('td')
  .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
  .parent()
  .find('td > div')
  .slideUp('fast');
   $(this).addClass('collapsed');
}
});

//Table Remove Button action
$('.tableRevmoveButton').click(function() {
     $('.tabel').remove();
     console.log('Remove table');
 });

//Table add Button action für add
$('.tableAddButton').click(function() {
   $('body').append('.tabel');
   console.log('Add table');
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $('body').append('<table><thead> [ ...]</table>');

Comment: Thanks. I see, just to write it inside the append method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have class for table which i guess you are having `.tabel` then use this

```
    $('.tableAddButton').click(function() {
   $('body').addClass('.tabel');
   console.log('Add table');
});
```

but if dont have a class and want to create table with html code in script then

```
$('.tableAddButton').click(function() {
   $('body').append('<table><thead>...</thead>...</table>');
   console.log('Add table');
});
```

or if you want only table in the body

```
 $('.tableAddButton').click(function() {
       $('body').html('<table><thead>...</thead>...</table>');
       console.log('Add table');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too difficult using the .append() JQuery function. When the button is clicked, select the tableDiv that you want to add the new table to, and then append table html.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#tableDiv").append("<table><tr><th>Appended table</th></tr></table>");
});
```